# Show $\left | \cosh{x}-1 \right |\leq 3 \left | x \right |$ for $\left | x \right |<1/2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, inequality, hyperbolic-functions

I have to show that $\left | \cosh{x}-1 \right |\leq 3 \left | x \right |$ for $\left | x \right |<1/2$. I can not use derivatives, series of the trigonometric functions etc. I have to use generel inequalities i.e like  $$1+x\le e^x\le\frac{1}{1-x}$$

How would I do this. I am completely lost. I know the definition of hyperbolic cosine but I can not work this one out.

Comment: 'etc.' covers a lot of ground here. $e^x-1 \leq (e-1)x$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$ by convexity of the exponential; that's more than enough to show it.

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes that is true :). It is fixed now.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Agreed, however this is unfortunately given to me in a very 'annoying' way. I can not use things that I have not prieviously shown. Any properties of the exponential functions are not really shown only a lot of inequalities.

Comment: @PierreCarre The whole things is fixed and this is how it was given to me. This is the exact problem. Note, it is the absolute value.

Comment: For $0\leq x \leq \frac 12$, you need to show that $\cosh x \leq 3x+1$. And, for $-\frac 12 \leq x <0$, you need to show that $\cosh x \leq -3x +1$.

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes I am having trouble with that. New to analysis so I would normally just use derivatives. I am having problems formally showing that both inequalities hold for all values in the interval.

Comment: Let's focus on $x \ge 0$. We want to show that $\cosh x \leq 3x + 1$. Given the convexity of $\cosh x$, you just need to show that $ \cosh \frac 12 < \frac 52$.

Comment: Without knowing what you've shown already and what tools particularly you're allowed to use, we have to play a guessing game as to what approaches are 'valid'. I mostly hold this against your instructors, not you, but it unfortunately makes this question a poor fit for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First proof** We know that $\text{ cosh} \left(x\right)-1 = 2 {\text{ sinh}}^{2} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$. Let $t = \left|x\right|/2$, it remains to prove that

\begin{equation}
0  \leqslant  t  \leqslant  \frac{1}{4} \Longrightarrow  {\text{ sinh}}^{2} \left(t\right)  \leqslant  3 t
\end{equation}

For such $t$, we have

\begin{equation}
\text{ sinh} \left(t\right)  \leqslant  \frac{1}{2} \left({e}^{t}-1\right)  \leqslant  \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{\left(1-t\right)}-1\right)  \leqslant  \frac{t}{2 \left(1-t\right)}
\end{equation}

It remains to prove that $\frac{t^2}{4 \left(1-t\right)^2}  \leqslant  3 t$ for
$t \in  I = \left[0 , 1/4\right]$, but this is equivalent to
$P(t) = 12 t^2 - 25 t + 12\ge 0$, which is true because the roots of $P$ are $3/4$ and $4/3$.

**Second proof**
It suffices to prove the result for $0\le x\le 1/2$. For such $x$ we have
\begin{equation}
\cosh x - 1 = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}- 1 \le e^x - 1 \le \frac{1}{1-x} - 1 = \frac{x}{1-x}
\end{equation}
It remains to show that $\frac{x}{1-x}\le 3 x$ but this is equivalent to $1\le 3 (1-x)$, that is to say $x\le \frac{2}{3}$, which is true. QED

Comment: Is there no way to prove it using the inequality given in the post? This is a bit too difficult for me as I am new in analysis.

Comment: Which inequality? I used $e^x\le 1/(1-x)$

Comment: I guess this is a good indicator of how *out of it* I currently am. I just can not seem to get the process and thus the conclusion and how it relates to the main problem that we are trying to show.

Comment: See my edit for a simpler and hopefully better proof

Comment: You are a life-saver. This makes sense now. Analysis feels incredibly difficult for me currently which is weird coming from my last course where i scored a 99% in linear algebra. I feel beyond dumb at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

$\cosh(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$
so,
if $0 \le x \le a < 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
\cosh(x)-1
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
&=x^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n-2}}{(2n)!}\\
&=x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n+2)!}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n+2)!/2}\\
&\le\dfrac{x^2}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n}\\
&\le\dfrac{x^2}{2(1-x^2)}\\
&=x\dfrac{x}{2(1-x^2)}\\
&\le x\dfrac{a}{2(1-a^2)}
\qquad\text{since } \dfrac{x}{1-x^2} \text{ in increasing for }0 < x < 1\\
\end{array}
$

If $a = \dfrac12$,
$\dfrac{a}{2(1-a^2)}
=\dfrac{1/2}{2(1-1/4)}
=\dfrac{1}{4(3/4)}
=\dfrac13
$

so
$|\cosh(x)-1|
\le x/3$
for
$|x| \le \dfrac12$
(actually, according to Wolfy,
for $|x| \lt 0.644$).

Comment: While this absolutely works, power series are one of the things explicitly ruled out by OP.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes unfortunately. I was only given the inequality written out in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on positive $x$ (symmetry takes care of the rest), we need to show that, for $x\in[0,\frac 12]$, we have $\cosh x \leq 3x + 1$.

Assuming that you can use the fact that $\cosh x$ is a convex function, you know that $\cosh x \leq  2 \cosh \frac 12 \cdot x$, when $x \in [0,\frac 12]$. So, we just need to show that $2\cosh \frac 12 \cdot x \leq 3x+1$.